# Why does my url keep getting changed by vue.js routing?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have a pretty simple page right now that I'm just setting up for future development but it's kind of come to a halt now that my URL keeps getting changed.

```
import shipmentInformation from './shipment-information.vue';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

let router = new VueRouter({
    base: '/QuickQuote/QuickQuoteRefactor/',
    routes: [
        { name: 'shipmentInformation', path: '/', component: shipmentInformation }
    ]
});

new Vue({
    router
}).$mount('#quickQuoteApp')
```

This is run on a page where #quickQuoteApp contains a `<router-view>` element. Users get to this page by navigating to (on local machine) `localhost/QuickQuote/QuickQuoteRefactor`. The components load and I see the hash get added to the end of the url for a split second (`localhost/QuickQuote/QuickQuoteRefactor#`) before it changes to `localhost/#/` for some reason.

Any ideas on why this is happening. I thought the 'base' option was supposed to take care of this.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that this was caused by a conflict between vue-router and jquery.history.js

Not sure of the exact cause but it looked like History was trying to 'correct' the hash changes in the url made by vue-router, therefore breaking it.

Comment: I have no history.js nor any other history state library, still the url is being changed to /#/ under Firefox :<